# NameError: name 'Merge' is not defined

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to merge 2 convolutional layers. Code is given below:

> `convs = []`
>
> `for k_no in range(len(kernel_size)):`
>
> ```
>   `conv = Convolution2D(nb_filters, kernel_size[k_no][0],kernel_size[k_no][1],
>                          border_mode='same',
>                          activation='relu',
>                          input_shape=input_shape)(inp)`                         
>    `pool = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=pool_size)(conv)`
> ```
>
> `convs.append(pool)`
>
> `if len(kernel_size) > 1:`
>
> ```
>   `out = Merge(mode='concat')(convs)`
> ```
>
> `else:`
>
> ```
>   `out = convs[0]`
> ```
>
> `conv_model = Model(input=inp, output=out)`

I get the following error:-

> NameError: name 'Merge' is not defined

How can I solve this? If someone knows the answer, kindly reply.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you forgot to import `merge`, I assume you are using Keras. Add this line at the top of your code

```
from keras.layers import Merge
```